# April Challenges

Tags: discussion, challenges

Alright, since today is April 2nd, I'm past due for the monthly challenges. This month isn't going to be too much different. We're still looking for voting improvements, so voting is where the main part is going to be at.

1. The first part of the challenge is going to be based towards newer people here on Mechanics.SE. This challenge is the [**Civic-Duty Badge**](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) challenge. This challenge requires you to vote 300 times. Up. Down. Question. Answer. Doesn't matter. All you have to do is have voted 300 times to garner the badge. Earn the badge this month and receive **50 points**.
2. The second part of the challenge is based towards those who have been here a little while, yet still aren't as active as they could be. This challenge is the [**Research Assistant Badge**](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/79/research-assistant) challenge. To complete this challenge, you need to edit 50 [wiki tags](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/tags?tab=new). There are a lot of new tags out there which need content. Edit 50 of those tags by inserting good content and you'll earn the badge. This takes a little bit of time and effort to accomplish. The wiki excerpts do not count towards this badge, just the wiki's themselves. You can copy content from Wikipedia or any other source you find, but ensure you are giving attribution when doing so (links/references). The better the information, the better it is for the site. Earn this badge and garner **100 points**.
3. The third challenge anyone can participate in (well, anyone can participate in any of these challenges, lol). This is the [**Electorate Badge**](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate) challenge. Vote on 600 questions with 25% or more of total votes on questions and you'll earn this badge. Some of you will have a long way to go to earn this, others just a few votes. Either way, the main emphasis is voting on questions. It doesn't matter if the votes are up or down, it just requires you to vote on questions. You can vote up to 40 times per day. It won't take too long to wrap up this badge. Earn the badge this month and receive **200 points**.

As with previous challenges, all points will be awarded from my stash of points. The points will be awarded after the month is over. You've got the entire month to earn any or all of the badges, so all you have to do is get busy! I hope you enjoy this month's challenges.

Comment: Since the user @costrom earned the [civic-duty badge](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty) right at the end of March, I'm willing to include them as the first person to complete this challenge! Congrats!

Comment: That's a pretty sweet April package you've got going there.

Comment: @DucatiKiller - I don't have a clue who could have helped me figure it out :o)

Comment: @stewart or TenaciousP probably.

Comment: Wow! Congrats to @Sue for qualifying for the Civic Duty Challenge!

Comment: Congrats to @GrindingMetal as well! You also completed the Civic Duty Challenge!

Comment: And yet another!!! Congrats @Chenmunka for completing my Civic Duty Challenge :o)

Comment: Thank you @JPhi1618 for voting and completely the Civic Duty Challenge!

Comment: Does it count if I got the Civic Duty like 7 months ago? ;)

Comment: @George - well, no, but there are two other badges to shoot for! :o)

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Ah dammit! ;)

Comment: Congratulations to @FredWilson who has completed the Research Assistant Badge Challenge! Great job!

Comment: Congratulations to @Mikes for completing the Civic Duty Challenge! That is awesome sauce right there!

Comment: Congratulations to @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing for completing the Electorate challenge! Great job!

Comment: Congratulations to @MooseLucifer for completing the Civic Duty Challenge! Thanks for taking this on!

Comment: Congratulations to @LynnCrumbling for completing the Civic Duty Challenge! We appreciate your votes!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Congratulations are in order for the following:

**[Electorate Badge Challenge](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/44/electorate)**

- @IhavenoideawhatI'mdoing

**[Research Assistant Badge Challenge](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/79/research-assistant)**

- @FredWilson

**[Civic Duty Badge Challenge](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/help/badges/32/civic-duty)**

- @costrom
- @Sue
- @GrindingMetal
- @Chenmunka
- @JPhi1618
- @Mikes
- @MooseLucifer
- @LynnCrumbling

Everyone please give all a round of applause (if that were at all possible over the internet)! I appreciate your having taken on my challenges and surpassed them! Great job!

(Editorial note: I will be paying out the points over the next few days. I can only have three bounties up at a time, and then need 24 hours for them to be in place before I can award them. Also, If any of you do not have a *good* answer for me to throw this on, I'll need to wait until you do. Most notably, @Sue. Sorry sweet lady, you don't even have one answer I can post this on. I'll be glad to do so when it is present ... we'll call those points *in escrow*. It appears that @costrom will be in the same shape, I'm sorry to say. I'm also going to have to put @GrindingMetal's points into escrow. While they have two answers, those answers don't really qualify as *good* answers.)

Answer (score 0):

It's May! Any new challenges? (I don't have enough points to spare to donate!)

Comment: Not yet. I may do one half way through the month for both May/June, though.